# Best optimizer for multiclass classification

Tags: classification

I am looking for the best optimizer for a multiclass classification problem, because my results aren't very good and I am pretty sure the optimizer is the problem. Also, a good learning rate for an optimizer or a learning rate schedule would also be appreciated. I tried google search but it didn't give me optimizers. To summarize, I am looking for an optimizer, a good learning rate, or a good learning rate schedule for a multiclass classification problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.